# Monitor or restart RFID thread on Raspberry Pi - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am building a Raspberry TimeClock that uses the MFRC522 RFID module.
Have everything working fine to upload to a database but occasionally I have a glitch on the backthread that monitors RFID scans
The thread stops picking up scans. Front Panel display tkinter widgets continue to function normally. I can re-create loss of RFID scanning by temporarily disconnecting one of the RFID leads.
When I check that the backThread is still running via  backThread.is_Alive – I get true that it is.
My question:

1. – is the backthread truly running? If so do I need to re-initialize the SPI buss – if so How
2. How can I utilize a heartbeat or other to determine the backthread is actually up and running
   Any help is appreciated
   Thanks – Dan

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label
from types import SimpleNamespace    
import threading  
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue  
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/MFRC522-python')
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()
# Global Font Settings
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 28)
CLOCK_FONT= ("Verdana", 92)
ACCEPT_FONT= ("Verdana", 60)
def queHandler(qData,): #Monitors que from BackThread
    while True:
        empData = qData.get() #check for punch       
        intEmpNo= empData[:5]
        strEmpName= empData[6:]
        strEmpName =strEmpName.strip() 
        print(1)
        print(intEmpNo)
        print(strEmpName)     
        PunchEvent(intEmpNo, strEmpName) #Send to PunchEvent Handler  
def MainGui(root, qData):
    root.configure(background="darkblue")
    root.geometry("800x480+560+300")
    #root.geometry("800x480")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.overrideredirect(1)    
    txtLabelVar1 = tk.StringVar()
    txtLabelVar1.set("")
    lblEmpName = tk.Label(root, justify="right", bg="darkblue",fg="yellow", highlightbackground="darkblue",relief="flat",font = "monaco 32 ", textvariable=txtLabelVar1)
    lblEmpName.place(x=20,y=275,width=760,height=50)
    txtLabelVar2 = tk.StringVar()   
    txtLabelVar2.set("")
    lblPunchStat = tk.Label(root, justify="right", bg="darkblue",fg="yellow", highlightbackground="darkblue",relief="flat",font = "monaco 38 ", textvariable=txtLabelVar2)
    lblPunchStat.place(x=20,y=360,width=760,height=40)
    return SimpleNamespace(txtLabelVar1=txtLabelVar1, txtLabelVar2=txtLabelVar2)
def PunchEvent(intEmpNo, strEmpName):  
    guiref.txtLabelVar2.set(str(intEmpNo) + " " + strEmpName)
def backRFIDthread(root, qData):        
    while True:      
        try:      
            id, text = reader.read()
            strName = text
            qData.put(strName)          
        except Exception as e: print(e)               
    GPIO.cleanup() 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    qData = Queue() 
    guiref = MainGui(root, qData)
    backThread = threading.Thread(target = backRFIDthread, args =(root, qData, )) #Changed to threading.Thread
    backThread.daemon = True
    backThread.start()   
    t = Thread(target=queHandler, args=(qData,))    
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can try `id, text = reader.read_no_block()` instead of `id, text = reader.read()`, but you need to check whether `id` is not `None` before putting `text` into queue.  Then you can print something to the console or update a label in the `while` loop to see whether the thread is running.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thanks so much for your input